# haskell Convert IO Int to Int System.Random.MWC

Tags: haskell, io

I would like to convert an `IO Int` to `Int` from `System.Random.MWC`, using `unsafePerformIO`. It does work in ghci:

```
Prelude System.Random.MWC System.IO.Unsafe> let p = unsafePerformIO(uniformR (0, 30) gen :: IO Int)

Prelude System.Random.MWC System.IO.Unsafe> p

11

Prelude System.Random.MWC System.IO.Unsafe> :t p

p :: Int
```

However in GHC

```
import System.Random.MWC
import System.IO.Unsafe  

main :: IO()
main = do
        gen <-createSystemRandom
        print $! s 30 gen

s :: Int-> GenIO -> Int
s !k g = unsafePerformIO(uniformR (0, k - 1) g)
```

it returns

```
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
(GHC version 7.6.3 for i386-unknown-linux):
make_exp (App _ (Coercion _))

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
```

Comment: Why would think it's a good idea to do that? There's a very good reason that this yields `IO Int` and not `Int`: it is _not_ an actual integer value, just a "recipe" to obtain such a value. If ghci actually implements this as merely a "concealed" value of type `Int` and you are thus able to obtain a random number with `unsafeCoerce`, then that's more luck than anything else.

Comment: The usual answer is "it's called *unsafe* for a reason", but oftentimes people find that there isn't much of a downside to using it judiciously. This is not one of those times however—`mwc-random` is a pretty aggressively optimized library which unpacks and inlines a whole load of function bodies when called. The end result is that it makes for a hostile environment for `unsafe*` calls.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread, you didn't actually use `unsafeCoerce` but just `unsafePerformIO` – that's _less wrong_. If you need this as part of a randomised (but deterministic, please!) algorithm, then it should indeed be ok to make this a pure function with help of `unsafePerformIO`, but do it only around your entire algorithm, because for the single random numbers (which are _obviously_ not deterministic!) this is not meaningful. On the end result however, it's reasonable and should also not cause any of the problems that are likely to happen due to inlining issues, as J. Abrahamson says.

Answer (score 5):

There's really no need for `unsafePerformIO` here. Just change the type of `s` to return `IO Int` and use do-notation or the bind operator to feed the result to `print`.

```
s :: Int -> GenIO -> IO Int
s k g = uniformR (0, k - 1) g

main :: IO ()
main = do
    gen <- createSystemRandom
    x <- s 30 gen
    print x
```

or

```
main = do
    gen <- createSystemRandom
    print =<< s 30 gen
```

or

```
main = print =<< s 30 =<< createSystemRandom
```

Comment: I need the result in my programm. Actually I would like to shuffle a permutation as a product of transposition chosen randomly (Fisher Yates algorithm)

Comment: @user2746080: In that case, you should modify your code to also work in `IO` and write your shuffle function with do-notation. Then you can get the result using `<-` just like I've done here.

Comment: With System.Random my Shuffle function:
     shuffle :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [Integer]
     shuffle xs 1  = xs
     shuffle !xs !k  = shuffle (sswap (unsafePerformIO  (getStdRandom (randomR (0 , k - 1))) ) k xs) (k - 1) 
and it call the sswap function:
sswap :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
sswap !i !j !xs = genericTake i xs ++ [xs !! (fromIntegral j)] ++ (genericTake (j - i - 1) $ genericDrop (i + 1) xs) ++ [xs !! (fromIntegral i)] ++ genericDrop (j + 1) xs
It works fine but I don't know to write it with do notation. Appreciate help.

Comment: @user2746080: Try [something like this](https://gist.github.com/ahammar/9061298).

Comment: @user2746080 Perhaps you should read up on do-notation and monads: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation

Comment: I would like to use System.Random.MWC not System.Random. With System.Random my function works fine and I don't need to write it with do notation.

Comment: No, it does not "work fine". Lucky circumstances is what makes it do what you want in your case.

Comment: Add {-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import System.IO.Unsafe                                          
import System.Random
import Data.List

main :: IO()
main = do
 print.s $! [0..31]

s p = shuffle p (genericLength p - 1)
And it works.